# Angular Router - Restrict direct access to route. Only accessible from in-app routing

Tags: angular

I have a basic parent/child route configuration with lazy loading.

```
/ (root)
  -> myprofile
     -> edit
```

However, the component loaded for the `edit` route relies on a `state` being passed from the internal angular router, since it will pass info back and forth from it.

This causes some undesired behavior if a user would refresh at `/myprofile/edit` since no router state exists.

Right now I check the state, and use `router.navigate()` to go back to the `/myprofile` page in the `edit.component` upon initialization, but I don't feel like that's the most angular way to go about this.

Is there a way to build a guard around the route that it can only be accessed from the Angular Router?

Comment: is the state value you're passing around a simple value like a number or string?  or is it more complex like an object or function?

Comment: Complex like objects and functions. Otherwise I'd use parameters in the URL.

Comment: If you use a route guard that blocks the direct navigation, would the user experience be any better than what you currently offer?  Wouldn't the user just see a blank page (since there was no previous router state) and think your site is broken?

Comment: Well its more that it navigates to the page, loads, then sees there's no valid state, then navigates TO the parent component, but doesn't destroy. So when it navigates back with valid state, it doesn't go through the initialization again because it's already loaded in the component stack. So I'm looking to intercept it a bit further up the chain.

Comment: Ok.  How about just injecting `ActivatedRoute` or `Router` (not sure which) in your route guard, checking whether the stuff your component would need is available, and if it's not, then navigate to the profile and return `false` directly from the route guard?

Answer (score 0):

When a user refreshes an Angular route, the web server responds and serves the `index.html`, then Angular takes over, reads the URL and pushes the corresponding state with the [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/History) JavaScript API.

You could implement your own logic by testing if the `state` exists, in a guard. In Angular, there is no built-in feature to know whether a navigation is the first navigation or not, so if you don't want to implement a guard, the best solution is to configure your web server (Apache, Nginx or whatever you use) to send a 302 `Location: /myprofile` when receiving a `/myprofile/edit` request.